# Datepicker not working (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I try the code on this website: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3009/multiple-date-picker-functionality-in-jquery

When I try this code, there is nothing that works. I also looked at other tutorial it's always the same result. An empty textbox or a blank page.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
 $(function () {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
     numberOfMonths: 4,
     showButtonPanel: true
   });
  });
</script>
  
<body> 
 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>
</body>

</html>
```

The code works with code snippet...

Comment: "not working" is not a good explanation - What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Where / how are you using the posted HTML? Check your browser's console for errors and post them if there'sany

Comment: PS: when I run the code snippet and click on the textbox the datepicker is being shown and I'm able to select a date

Comment: I want this https://i.imgur.com/KJq1spO.png but I have this result https://i.imgur.com/Hy1RDc2.png t

Comment: @RuiJarimba I know. I said on the question that it works here but not when I run it with visual studio

Comment: For any reason your script file could not load i think. Please check your browser's console

Comment: I have three warnings. "code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js and code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" can not be found. And The "script" element can not be embedded in the "html" element

Comment: Why it can't find ?

Comment: Try and change the `//` in the CDN addresses to `https://` then run in Visual Studio... wonder if that is why it cannot load the scripts for you..the `//` preceding the scripts host URLs will work fine in a browser which is why they work here..

Comment: I change. But it's not work

Comment: @MichielSallaets, do you get same problem if you deploy the script files locally?

Comment: @derloopkat I can't do that. I want use a link...

Comment: @MichielSallaets, this is just for testing. Your code worked for the other guys including me and you claim the error is jquery.js could not be found, so it's possible that something is preventing your browser to download the file.

Comment: Ok I will try it.

Comment: As this code works properly in HTML, we would need to see how it's being created by ASP MVC. If jQuery library is not loading, then it will not work. Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: Same error when I install the library. "TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments yes it will work; as script is going to run on document.ready(). Correcting my answer; but still it is good practice to keep script tags bottom of the html after body.

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com//ui//1.11.2//themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com//jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com//ui//1.11.2//jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head> 
  <body> 
   <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>
  </body>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 4,
        showButtonPanel: true
      });
     });
   </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: It's not work. I have the same result. So, a textbox that is not work... I have the same warnings.

Comment: Wrong. OP has wrapped the script in `$(function () {` (an alias for `$(document).ready() {`)

Comment: @RahulRaut I have this "code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js and code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" can not be found. And The "script" element can not be embedded in the "html" element...

Comment: @RahulRaut this is not correct. The use of the `$()` wrapper is similar to `$(document).ready()` meaning the code will not execute until the document is fully loaded and ready. So placement of `<script>` tag is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @MichielSallaets The screenshot you have attached is of visual studio and it is suggesting to add javascript code in a separate file. I wanted to see error in browser. In most possible case browser is not able to locate your jquery and JqueryUI library files. If you open the browser console, it will actually show where its pointing file location.

Comment: @RahulRaut  I have this error in my browser (console): TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: @MichielSallaets, are you including the script before calling the function?